# Python Assertion error during argument parsing

Tags: python, arguments, assertion

I'm porting over an existing script, that works perfectly on my coworkers computer that gets an .elf file in the arguments and generates a .vbf from it. It boggles my mind because all other scripts ran fine on my computer. I run it with python 2.7.15.

vbf_builder_1_21_2.py --asw D:\tmp\FC8R009T4D3-20180523-182234.elf

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Bence/Python/Ford/pupp_package/Ford_FC8_VBFbuilder/vbf_builder_1_21_2.py", line 1296, in <module>
    CustomerBuildScript().print_step("Get environment information")
  File "D:/Bence/Python/Ford/pupp_package/Ford_FC8_VBFbuilder/vbf_builder_1_21_2.py", line 482, in __init__
    self.initialize()
  File "D:\Bence\Python\Ford\pupp_package\Ford_FC8_VBFbuilder\BuildScriptBase.py", line 26, in initialize
    self.parseArguments()
  File "D:\Bence\Python\Ford\pupp_package\Ford_FC8_VBFbuilder\BuildScriptBase.py", line 80, in parseArguments
    self.args = parser.parse_args()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\argparse.py", line 1701, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\argparse.py", line 1733, in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\argparse.py", line 1957, in _parse_known_args
    self.error(_('argument %s is required') % name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\argparse.py", line 2373, in error
    self.print_usage(_sys.stderr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\argparse.py", line 2335, in print_usage
    self._print_message(self.format_usage(), file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\argparse.py", line 2291, in format_usage
    return formatter.format_help()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\argparse.py", line 281, in format_help
    help = self._root_section.format_help()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\argparse.py", line 211, in format_help
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\argparse.py", line 332, in _format_usage
    assert ' '.join(opt_parts) == opt_usage
AssertionError

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have read that the error occurs usually when there's a long code that gets chopped up and it contains square brackets and that it was fixed but it still pops up.

EDIT: Realized what the problem was.[Spaces.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY5Te.png)

The coworker who last edited the script wanted to make it look neat so he aligned the parameter list declaration in a way so that the comma's are below eachother. At one parameter he accidentally put the spaces inside the name instead of outside of it. This space characters made the argumentparser mess up when he chopped the raw string up to parameters.

When you're sugaring up your code make sure to test it out again before passing it on to others.

Comment: Can you share the code that causes the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realized what the problem was. [Spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qz06i.png).

The coworker who last edited the script wanted to make it look neat so he aligned the parameter list declaration in a way so that the comma's are below eachother. At one parameter he accidentally put the spaces inside the name instead of outside of it. This space characters made the argumentparser mess up when he chopped the raw string up to parameters.

When you're sugaring up your code make sure to test it out again before passing it on to others.